# Sending signals to privileged processes started with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I started a privileged process through `Popen` class. I am now trying to signal to it but need to send signal as root.

Tried to send signal to the process through `Popen.send_signal(signal)` but I am getting error `'operation not permitted'`.

Obviously need to send signal as root, but I do not want to spawn another process like `subprocess.Popen('sudo kill -s signal pid', etc.)`.

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import signal

p1 = Popen(args2, stdout=PIPE)
while True:
    p1.send_signal(signal.SIGINFO)
    print(p1.stdout.readline())
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue. ``p1.send_signal(signal.SIGINFO)`` works fine for me without root privileges.

Comment: It's what the trace indicates: `p1.send_signal(signal.SIGINFO) PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`

Comment: Please provide a complete, verifiable example that replicates your issue. For example, what is ``args2``?